# Android: how to call a non-static function from C2DMBaseReceiver?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am using android-c2dm, and my device successfully receives messages from it. I want to call a non-static function (in an already-existing Activity) to do something with that message, but simply calling it from C2DMBaseReceiver is illegal. How can I transfer this information back to the activity?

Edit: What if I call a static function to assign variables (or set Shared Preferences), then call a handler which will use those variables to do what needs to be done? Is that bad style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is put the message details in an Intent somehow (the crudest way would be serialize the message to a String and add it as an Intent extra) and then send that Intent to the Activity using `startActivity`. The Activity could check for the extra, know that it is a message, extract and deserialize the message and then go to town.

You might need to set the appropriate launch mode or Intent flags if you want to make sure that an existing instance of the target Activity receives the message.

Comment: I forgot to include this originally, the Activity already exists. Basically I want to change a text view as soon as it gets a message from my server. startActivity wouldn't work for that would it?

Comment: Activity can be not in background(not visible) or even not started. if activity is not started you can't change TextView because it doesn't exist in that time.

Comment: If an instance of the activity exists you can use onNewIntent to update it.

Comment: I recently found that on a different question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get message from Intent in onMessage method, then show Notification and startActivity after user clicks on Notification. You can use Intent flags for bring background activity in foreground.
So if activity is not started - it will be started, if activity in background - it will be show in foreground and if it in foreground - then we need only change TextView text.
You also can startActivity without showing Notification.
Also you can use onNewIntent(Intent intent) Activity method for changing text. You can put message from google intent in onMessage into new Intent and startActivity with this intent and  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag.